# database connection through oops

Tags: php, pdo

I am developing a database connection with OOP PHP and PDO, and I am stuck on this error:

> Warning: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\VICAS\assets\dbfiles\config.php on line 29
> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: PDO::__construct(): Argument #4 ($options) must be of type ?array, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\VICAS\assets\dbfiles\config.php:29 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\VICAS\assets\dbfiles\config.php(29): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'root', '', 'Array') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\VICAS\pageincludes\image.php(4): vicass->__construct() #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\VICAS\assets\dbfiles\config.php on line 29

I am new to OOP so any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php

class vicass
{
    var $host;
    var $username;
    var $password;
    var $database;
    var $connect;
    var $home_page;
    var $query;
    var $data;
    var $statement;
    var $filedata;
    var $options;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->host = 'localhost';
        $this->username = 'root';
        $this->password = '';
        $this->database = 'vicas';
        $this->home_page = 'http://localhost/Vicas/index.php';
        $this->options = array(
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
            PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_OBJ,
            PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
        );

        $this->connect = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->host; dbname=$this->database", "$this->username", "$this->password", "$this->options");

        session_start();
    }

    function execute_query()
    {
        $this->statement = $this->connect->prepare($this->query);
        $this->statement->execute($this->data);
    }

    function total_row()
    {
        $this->execute_query();
        return $this->statement->rowCount();
    }

    function redirect($page)
    {
        header('location:'.$page.'');
        exit;
    }
}
?>
```

If I exclude the options then it works, but I need to add those
options...please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with "OOP", the warning PHP gives you is in this case completely self-explanatory.

[PDO::__construct](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php) expects the `$options` parameter to be an array, and here

```
$this->connect = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->host; dbname=$this->database", "$this->username", "$this->password", "$this->options");
```

you are wrapping it in double quotes which turns it into a string - hence the error (because PHP doesn't automatically know how to represent an array in string format).

Remove those double quotes to pass the array to `__construct`.

N.B. The quote marks around the username and password variables are redundant, since those variables already contain strings (and for those parameters, a string is expected).

```
$this->connect = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->host; dbname=$this->database", $this->username, $this->password, $this->options);
```

Comment: I edited it for you to make the explanation clearer and provide the working version. Have an upvote on me.